# Plot a function on a log-log axis in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to verify the order of a numerical method in log-log axis. I've extracted my data from matlab and i wrote this on Tex:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line = left,xlabel=$space step$,ymode=log,xmode=log,grid=both,
major grid style={black!50}]
\addplot[mark=none] table{orderspace.txt};
\end{axis}
```

I want to put on the same graph a power function such as y=x² to verify the order. How can I do that?

Comment: That should be possible by simply adding `\addplot [domain=0:100] {x^2};` (where `0:100` has to be replaced by the domain over which you want to plot the function). Could you give that a shot?

Comment: It doesn't work, i tried \addplot [domain=0.001:0.1] {x^2} and i have multiples errors : "! Paragraph ended before \pgfplots@PREPARE@COORD@STREAM@end@ was complete.", "! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).", "! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode." ...

Comment: That sounds like you're missing the `;` at the end of the command. If you still get an error, please edit your question to turn the code into a minimal compilable document (starting from `\documentclass`), otherwise there's too much guesswork involved.

Comment: Great, I forgot the ;, it's working now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question was solved in the comments.